# NEAT multiple activation functions

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neat

I was wondering if a NEAT network could have multiple activation functions.

https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/activation.html

For example two neurons as an output: one sigmoid and one selu.

I also think if I change it in the config file to selu for example, all neurons would have the selu activation function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I would like to set all activation functions to sigmoid for all layers and outputs and only one output to selu for example.
Is this possible or am I just talking non-sense here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Python implementation, but it is certainly not nonsense. The C# implementation I used actually allowed different activation functions. I believe this is because it was also used to implement Hyper-NEAT. Trying to have all outputs with one activation and one with another sounds a bit weird, though. If your problem is really outputs, have you considered using an external function to transform the problematic output? (I mean as a postprocessing step, outside the reach of NEAT).

Comment: I just couldn't find a way to manually change what you would like it to be. Only adjustment to be made is setting which optional functions you allow and to set a probability that it changes another. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry I couln't be more helpful. I take it in the implementation you are using you cannot choose those functions separately for different types of neurons, right? Like this set of functions for hidden, this set for output neurons.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I think that is probably the key feature of NEAT. It finds the "best" possible structure.